# Completely lost when it comes to using the DrivePicker widget

Tags: google-app-maker

Obviously, I know how to drag the DrivePicker widget to a form.  But after that, I am completely clueless on how to work like a normal upload control.

I have a text box field with a google drive icon to the right of it.

The text box has the name exemptionAttachment.

The google drive icon has in the OnDocumentSelect and onDocumentSelect events the code: widget.parent.descendants.exemptionAttachment.value = result.docs[0].id;

All that really happens is when the user clicks on the drive icon, they select a file from their hard drive and the file id is put in the exemptionAttachment text box.

So after submitting the form, there is no attachment attached to the form or anything similar.  Perhaps I am missing the point of Google and that the file is supposed to get stored in google drive somewhere (though I don't where in terms of synching this to the application).

So basically, I'm kind of clueless in terms of uploading attachments in a form.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, files picked using Drive Picker are supposed to be stored in Drive, not your application. So, when you want to use those files later through your application, you should store the ID or URL of the file, instead of the file itself.

For example, I've got a DocumentUrl field in my datasource. And so, I've binded the DrivePicker widget's selectedDocUrl to @datasource.item.DocumentUrl. Now the widget saves the document's URL into datasource, and the link can be used later on.

I have also used scripts to share that document automatically by URL, so that every user can actually access the document.

```
// DrivePicker onDocumentSelect event:    
google.script.run.setSharingByUrl(widget.selectedDocId);
```

Serverside script:

```
// Shares Drive file by URL in domain, with comment privileges
function setSharingByUrl(fileId) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

  // Checking if file already has edit permission, since we don't want to lower that to comment permission
  if (file.getSharingPermission() === DriveApp.Permission.EDIT){
    return;
  }
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.COMMENT);
}
```

Hope that helps you understand DrivePicker more.

Check out these references and samples for more insight:

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/widgets#drive_picker
https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#Feature

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/drive-picker/
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/document-approval

Comment: Thanks!  Now I have a field with the file path to the attached file in Google Drive.  So a use to see the attached file (maybe I should stop using this terminology) has to copy and paste the url to another browser window?

Comment: You can use the 'file path' in a link widget, so that when the user clicks it, it opens automatically.

Comment: You're welcome! Also, please accept the solution if it actually solved the problem. I recommend doing this to your older questions too, it helps this community function better.